# Avoid Concat URL in React-Redux-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I am using react-router + react-router-redux in my app.
What I want to achieve is every time user click a tab in the `dashboard` it will change the URL to `/dashboard/messages`, for instance.

However, using `push('dashboard/' + page)`, every time I click a tab it will append the link.

My current situation:

1. Current URL is `/dashboard`.
2. Click a Messages tab.
3. The URL changes into `/dashboard/messages`.
4. Click a Home tab.
5. The URL changes into `/dashboard/messages/dashboard/home`.

Is there any way to just replace the `/dashboard/messages` into `/dashboard/home` when we click Home tab after cliked the Messages tab?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found the silly mistake, sorry for this.

So apparently it has to be `push('/dashboard/' + page)` instead of `push('dashboard/' + page)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're coming in here from a `react-router-dom` perspective, please note that `<Link to='stringUrl' />` concatenates whatever you place on the `to` attribute to the current `path`. So, if you are currently on `/home` path, it will produce `/home/StringUrl` as a result.

However, if you place a forward slash `/` instead, i.e. `<Link to='/stringUrl' />` it won't do that, thus producing `/StringUrl` path.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
push('/dashboard/' + page)
```

Comment: Why not? This answers the question. He even answered it again a second after with the same solution.